# How to copy destination to source on OnRenderImage

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a complete Unity Newbie, here.

I have the following script attached to the MainCamara of my app:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraRenderToImage : MonoBehaviour
{

    private int counter;

    public CameraRenderToImage(){
        counter = 0;
    }

    void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest)
    {
        Debug.Log("Render finalized " + counter);
        counter++;        
        //Graphics.CopyTexture(src, dest);
        dest = src;
    }

}
```

I need access to the finalized renderized image in src, but I don't want to actually modify the output. Just by adding this function the output of my screen (and Headset as this is using VR) goes black.

If I comment the function it works again.

I'm mostly sure that what is going on is that the source texture is not getting properly copied to the destination texture.

What I tried to do is to make equal (I assume this does not work becuase they are the equivalent of pointers) and use Graphics.CopyTexture which gives the following error:

```
Graphics.CopyTexture can only copy between same texture format groups (d3d11 base formats: src=9 dst=27)
```

Can anyone help me out? All I want is to make dest equal to source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this

```
dest = src;
```

does absolutely nothing. I know what you expected this to do but all it does is overwriting the reference stored in `dest` **locally**. It doesn't affect the previously passed in `dest` at all.

You assume correctly about the black screen. As soon as you implement `OnRenderImage` you are responsible for assuring that something is rendered into `dest`. You are not doing that / the error prevents it from happening.

Usually for this you rather use [`Graphics.Blit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.Blit.html) which doesn't underlay the format matching limitation

```
Graphics.Blit(src, dest);
```

Comment: Thank you, though note I did figure out that dest = src was wrong making it equivalente to equating a pointer revernces and hence doing nothing. But thanks for explaining it to me